# How to solve such integer program problem?

Tags: inequalities, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming

Consider a $3$-tuple $(a,b,s)$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_+,s\in\mathbb{Q}_+$. Denote $ab-s$ by $\Delta$. Let $A$ be a positive number. What are the values of $A$ such that for any $(a,b,s)$ with $\Delta\geq A$, the following system of inequalities in $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ always has solutions. What is the minimal value of $A$

$$\begin{cases}
\Delta\leq (-a-1+m)(-b-1+n)\\
\Delta\geq (-a-1+m)(-b+n)\\
\Delta\geq (-a+m)(-b+n-1)\\
\Delta\geq (-a+m)(-b+n)
\end{cases}$$

This problem can be solved by drawing a graph of parabola and elaborating the position of a point in a shift of standard lattice. But I am wondering whether there is some general strategy from integer program or related area. This is just a toy case of my real question. My real question has many more variables which makes the method of drawing graph impossible.

Comment: What is the relation of $A$ to the system of inequalities that you list? Is it correct to say that you want to solve: $\min A$ s.t. $A \leq \Delta$, $\Delta \leq (-a -1 + m)(-b-1 + n)$, $\Delta \geq \max( ...., ..., ... )$ where the max has the last three expressions you list? Here, inputs are $a,b,s$ (and $\Delta$) and variables are $m, n, A$ with $m,n$ integer.